# Android sqlite missing column

Tags: android, sqlite

My SQLite database is missing a column which I know exists. I will not be able to pull the database from the Android Emulator, because there is no way to populate it with the emulator without substantial code rewrite.

logcat returns `sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table items has no column named checkedout` when I add an item to this table. Below is the table declaration, and below that is the insert function. Do I spell checkedout inconsistently somewhere?

```
 static final String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE ="create table if not exists "+CHECKOUT_TABLE+" ("
        + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_STORE +" TEXT,"
        + KEY_INVID + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_PRODUCT + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_PRICE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_WEIGHT + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_QUANTITY + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_CHECKEDOUT + "INTEGER"
        + ");";



//store item
public long storeNewItem(String store, String invid, String product, 
        String price, String weight, String category, String quantity, int checkedout) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_STORE, store);
    initialValues.put(KEY_INVID, invid);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT, product);
    initialValues.put(KEY_WEIGHT, price);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, weight);
    initialValues.put(KEY_QUANTITY, quantity);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CHECKEDOUT, checkedout); //just in case I want to store these items, but server should know

    if(checkedout==0)
    {
        return sqlDb.insert(CHECKOUT_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
    else //if checkedout==true
    {
        return sqlDb.insert(PAST_ITEM_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are CHECKOUT_TABLE and PAST_ITEM_TABLE really defined the same?

Comment: yes. checkout_table will be cleared often and deleted. past_item_table will grow quite a bit and never be cleared until other limitations are reached

Comment: In DDMS perspective open File Explorer Tab find your database, pull on the disc, and check in e.g SQLite Browser database structure

Comment: which insert call produces the error?

Comment: @Mike on a real device the data folder does not display anything.

Comment: @hovanessyan the storeNewItem call. Passing `0` for the checkedout variable

Comment: @CQM Try with emulator, this not works on non-rooted device

Comment: won't make any difference in behavior, but wouldn't be  nice if you use insertOrThrow() instead of insert(). Next maybe wrap it up in transactons? Apart from that -everything in this code seems correct.

Comment: Post your SQLiteOpenHelper code.

Comment: answer posted, it was just a space in the declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer was that the last column did not have a space in the declaration

`+ KEY_QUANTITY + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_CHECKEDOUT + "INTEGER"
        + ");";`

should have been

`+ KEY_QUANTITY + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_CHECKEDOUT + " INTEGER"
        + ");";`

*sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't seem to be able to write this as a comment, so I put it down as an answer:

I assume you created the table with an earlier version of your program, where there was no "checkedout" column.
Now the table is not recreated, because you include "IF NOT EXISTS" in your query.

Try to remove the table first!